# Hibernate: replacement for deprecated AbstractPreDatabaseOperationEvent.getEntity()?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My application uses `org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEventListener` to do complex validations of entities prior to updates. It needs both the entity and the event so that we can see the specific fields changed (old state and new state).

Upgraded from Hibernate 5.3.13 to 5.3.28, and `org.hibernate.event.spi.AbstractPreDatabaseOperationEvent.getEntity()` is deprecated.

The only thing thing in the javadocs is `Support for JACC will be removed in 6.0`, which is not very helpful in terms of a replacement.

What is the recommended equivalent in Hibernate 6?
The JPA-spec `@PreUpdate` annotation does not give access to any sort of old/new state, so it's not enough for our needs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only using `getEntity()`, then it is fine.
As [@Deprecated to this method is a mistake](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/5f135863)

It appears in [5.3 deprecation list](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/deprecated-list.html) but not in [5.6 deprecation list](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/javadocs/deprecated-list.html)